# Beforeinstallprompt not getting called in in-app browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, chrome-custom-tabs, web-share

1. I have a pwa1 which will open in in-app browser of pwa2. I have install button for pwa1. But in in-app browser beforeinstallpromt is not getting fired. Any workaround for this?
2. `<a href="intent://stackoverflow.com#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.android.chrome;end"> Open in Chrome </a>` this link will open in chrome app from any other browser in Android except in-app browser of PWA. Any way to make it work for in-app browser?
3. Web share api shows lots of app when clicking share button except chrome app. Any way to add chrome app in sharing suggestions?

Comment: Some help here is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. No, this only works in [top-level browsing contexts](https://wicg.github.io/manifest-incubations/#dfn-present-an-install-prompt) according to the spec, but not in nested contexts.
2. Not that I know of, probably due to a similar limitation as above.
3. Chrome is not a share target, but you can copy the URL and open the URL on the clipboard with Chrome.